# in Next js Image i am using the following url `https://amandascookin.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/Crispy-Potatoes-680.jpg`. this is giving me `403`

Tags: reactjs, image, web, next.js, frontend

in Next js Image i am using the following url `https://amandascookin.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/Crispy-Potatoes-680.jpg`. this is giving me `403` . when i tried the same with a `nextjs` code-sandbox it is giving fine result. I am not sure why it is happening in my original project and in my next js config i am using the following

```
images: {
remotePatterns: [
  {
    protocol: "https",
    hostname: "**",
  },
  {
    protocol: "http",
    hostname: "**",
  },
],
```

},

Can someone help me in solving this?

Answer (score 0):

you can add a domain in the images config something like :

```
    images:{
    domains:["amandascookin.com"]
    }
```

This is in the next.config.js file in the root directory. Hope it helps.